# Issue with copying an SKAudioNode object

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaudionode

I am currently preloading sound effects in a dictionary, as such:

```
soundEffectsDictionary[SoundEffectType: SKAudioNode]
```

Doing this allows me to preload all the sound effects in the game, and request a sound effect as needed. I am simplifying this for demonstration purposes:

let fxBoom = soundEffectsDictionary[SoundEffectType.fxBoom]!.copy() as! SKAudioNode

This works in the same way for `SKSpriteNodes`, `SKTextures`, etc. However, it does not seem that `SKAudioNode` can produce copies in this way. When I try to add the copies to the screen, they do not play.

1. How can I properly copy `SKAudioNode`? If I want to play fxBoom twice, overlapping, then I will need two separate nodes. I do not want to load the file from disk for performance reasons, which is why I'm attempting to preload the sounds.
2. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is some simple code that demonstrates the issue:

```
    let audioNode = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "fxBoom.mp3")
    self.addChild(audioNode) //audio plays, looping indefinitely


    let audioNode = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "fxBoom.mp3")
    let audioNode2 = audioNode.copy() as! SKAudioNode
    self.addChild(audioNode2) // audio does not play
    audioNode2.run(SKAction.play()) // no difference
    audioNode2.isPaused = false // no difference
```

Comment: Did you run the the play action also on it?

Comment: Yes I did, still no sound.

Comment: could you post an example please?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Posted sample code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I thought you said you were running the play action?  Also make sure the node .isPaused is false

Comment: I did try the play action, I used audioNode2.run(SKAction.play()). I also put it into a runBlock with no success. Node isn't paused, but that was something I forgot to check.

Comment: try doing `SKAudioNode(avAudioNode:audioNode.avAudioNode) ` instead of a copy, I do not have XCode available right this second to figure out what is going wrong

Comment: OH, where are you doing this also?  I remember coming across an issue where the audio engine needs to be initialized before copies could happen.

Comment: That crashes the app with: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: file != nil'

Comment: yeah, looks like your avAudioNode is not properly initialized yet

Comment: I am attempting to do this in an Assets singleton, but right now I am testing just in a scene.

Comment: Interesting. Any idea how I can properly initialize it? I've tried everything I can think of at this point.

Comment: It has to do with when you are creating the assets,  i dont remember when the audio engine is created

Comment: But if the original sound node plays, wouldn't that show that the audio engine is initialized? Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: It doesnt play until the engine is ready,  the problem i think is you are copying something that isnt 100% finished, and the copy is not going to be in that loading state also.